# UITableView with UITableViews as children?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

Our designers gave us a design where the home page of our app is collection of different views scrollable vertically.

Some are images, others are custom sliders and then there are two (dynamic) lists, meaning that we need to create a `UITableView` that contains two more `UITableViews` as two of its cells.

We've managed to achieve that by making the child TableViews expanded (full heigth), so the parent cell knows what height to get. However, the child TableView's cells are not being reused, since the view controlelr does not know when to reuse the child cells, and they all get allocated when the TableView gets allocated, resulting in poor performance.

Is there a better way of achieving the "scrollable list of objects that contains lists of other objects" design? Can the child cells be reused?

We've also thought of using a `UICollectionView` as the parent "scrollable list" container, but the child cell reusability problem is still there. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe flatten the UI hierarchy? Instead of using nested UITableViews just insert the cells of the inner table views into the outer table view instead. Having nested UIScrollViews scrolling in the same direction sounds like bad UX anyways.

Comment: @Palle that is an interesting approach, I will try to figure out a way to do this. (the child TableViews have custom headings with custom menus and filters on the top, so that's why we're thinking of creating separate TableViewControllers to handle everything)